# Stepping problem in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, remote-debugging, eclipse-cdt

I have created a custom toolchain and launch configuration to allow debugging on a remote target.

I've got the debugging working so that I can step through each statement. However, the stepping doesn't always match up with the position in the code editor.

For example, when debugging this code:

```
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
```

The cursor will stay on the first line of the "for" statement rather than jumping onto the "printf" statement when stepping.

However, when I turn on "Instruction Stepping Mode" it does end up stepping onto the "printf" statement.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide anymore details.

Best regards,
Alan

Comment: how about the behavior when using gdb? I suspect your source code doesn't match the binary.

Comment: As far as I can tell, using gdb is stepping over everything that I would expect it to. What I should have mentioned though is that this is a Sparc cross compiler and it uses Newlib for things like printf... therefore it is a bit more difficult to correlate the command based gdb with the one in Eclipse because of these internal function calls for printf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to draw a line under this one, it was due to me having compiler optimizations turned on... turn them off and it works fine.

Alan